# Typo in decimal place + postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, validation, decimal, data-cleaning

I have a data set of students that calculates average scores (to the nearest decimal) as of a certain date.The data set is riddled with typos.
A sample data is:

```
student_id  date   avg_test_score
ab_1        1/2/20 95..6
ab_2        1/2/20 60.7
ab_3        2/4/20 88..7
ab_4        2/4/20 98.7.
```

This may seem straightforward but I'm having a difficult time with the query in postgresql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following regex update on the `avg_test_score` column:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET avg_test_score = SUBSTRING(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(avg_test_score, '\.{2,}', '.') FROM '\d+(?:\.\d+)?');
```

The above logic first replaces sequences of two or more dots with just a single dot.  Then we extract integer or floating point numbers from what remains.

Comment: Many thanks! @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: The REGEX_REPLACE function is so much helpful, you can do almost everything with it :) Great idea to do it that way.

Comment: A follow-up question -- the "avg_test_score" field was erroneously entered as a text field. What is the best approach to update the field to type=decimal place (to the nearest tenth) and correct for the redundant decimals?